# Implementation of a football ground booking system in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, view

I have two apps; turfs and booking. There is a Turf model in turfs app models.py which has the basic information about the ground. The booking app contains a model Booking which has info. about booking a ground.

I am stuck at writing the views part to get the available grounds to display after excluding the already booked grounds.

HTML Form:

```
<form>
    <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group date" id="datepicker1">
                            <label class="sr-only">Date From:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control rounded" required name="datein" placeholder="Date From"/>
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <i class="#"></i>
                            </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group date" id="datepicker2">
                            <label class="sr-only">Date To:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control rounded" required name="dateout" placeholder="Date To"/>
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <i class="#"></i>
                            </span>
                    </div>
                </div>

              </div>
              <!-- Form Row 2 -->
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                        <label class="sr-only">TimeIN</label>
                        <span style="font-family: Titillium Web, sans-serif;">Time in:</span>
                        <input type="time" required name="timein" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                  <label class="sr-only">TimeOUT</label>
                    <span style="font-family: Titillium Web, sans-serif;">Time out:</span>
                  <input type="time" required name="timeout" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
              <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-block mt-4" type="submit"> Check Availability</button>
            </form>
```

Turf Model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from datetime import datetime
# Create your models here.


class Turf(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    address = models.TextField()
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    district = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    photo_main = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    photo_1 = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True)
    photo_2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True)
    starting_time = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    closing_time = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    is_24hr = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    has_display = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    has_parking = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    sqft = models.IntegerField(default=20)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='hi')
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='hi')
    price_per_hour = models.IntegerField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    built = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Booking Model:

```
from django.db import models
from turfs.models import Turf
# Create your models here.

class Booking(models.Model):
    datein = models.DateField()
    dateout = models.DateField()
    time_in = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    time_out = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.TextField()
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    turf_id = models.ForeignKey(Turf, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: What is your question, exactly?

Comment: Sidenote, I recommend to not name you ForeignKeys with `_id`, since in the end under `booking.turf_id` you'll have the Turf object, and under `booking.turf_id_id` you'll have the id.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have cut short the question.

Comment: @mfrackowiak Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your `Booking` model to use datetime fields rather than a date and two strings.

```
class Booking(models.Model):
    start = models.DateTimeField()
    end = models.DateTimeField()
```

Then your view would look something like this:

```
requested_start # Some datetime
requested_end # Some datetime
is_available = not Booking.objects.filter(
    Q(start__range=[requested_start, requested_end])
    | Q(end__range=[requested_start, requested_end])
).exists()
```

You need to check for any start or end landing in the window of the requested booking, hence the Q objects being ORed.

Comment: This one seems to be almost working. Thanks!!!